# I need to call fragment from DataAdapter android

Tags: android

Here, My class is like this

```
public class TicketAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Ticket> {
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    TicketHolder holder = null;

    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
    row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

    holder = new TicketHolder();
    holder.ticket = items.get(position);
    holder.removeTicketButton = (ImageButton)row.findViewById(R.id.ticket_remove);
    holder.removeTicketButton.setTag(holder.ticket);

    holder.settingTicketButton=(ImageButton)row.findViewById(R.id.ticket_setting);
    holder.settingTicketButton.setTag(holder.ticket);

    holder.settingTicketButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {



    holder.name = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.ticket_name);
    setNameTextChangeListener(holder);
//  holder.value = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.atomPay_value);
//  setValueTextListeners(holder);

    row.setTag(holder);

    setupItem(holder);
    return row;
}
}
```

And my another java file is like this

```
public class FreeFragment extends Fragment
```

{

```
}
```

Here, I want to call FreeFragment class from TicketAdapter class. While clicking on (R.id.settingTicketButton) this button, FreeFragment need to be called. How to call this Fragment from DataAdapter? Is it possible? Please Help.

Comment: use interface and create a callback function

Comment: Thank you very much to all for your kind support...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution. I have written the following code in TicketAdapter.java file..

```
    holder.settingTicketButton=(ImageButton)row.findViewById(R.id.ticket_setting);
    holder.settingTicketButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {

            Fragment freeFragment = new FreeFragment();
            if (freeFragment != null)

                switchFragment(freeFragment);
            Log.e("adapter_click_setting","adapter_click_setting");
        }
    });
}

private void switchFragment(Fragment newFragment)
{

    if (context == null)
    {
        Log.e("null_context","nulllll");
         return;
    }
    if (context instanceof AddNewTicket) {
        Log.e("meth_calling","method_calling");
         AddNewTicket feeds = (AddNewTicket) context;
         feeds.switchContent(newFragment);  
    }
```

}

And I have written the following method in AddNewTicket.java file..

```
public void switchContent(android.support.v4.app.Fragment newFragment) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment).commit();

}
```

Here, the R.id.fragment_container is the id of my ticket_listview.xml file. I have declared FragmentLayout in my that Xml file....

Answer (score 0):

The best method would be passing the `FreeFragment` instance an a variable in the constructor of the `TicketAdapter`and store it inside the adapter.

If this is not feasible you can use the following approch.

```
Fragment fragment = ((Activity)context).getfragmentmanager.findfragmentById(R.id.your_fragment_container_id);
```

Add this code in the contructor

Comment: From where I will get the id of R.id.your_fragment_container_id?? please Help.. Its urgent..

Comment: it is the id used with `getfragmentmanager.add()`. The id to which the fragment is added

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't access `FreeFragment` directly from `TicketAdapter` because you don't know if the fragment is added and visible. I would define a method in owner activity that would be called from adapter. In this method check first if the fragment is not-null and then call whatever method from fragment. Something like (in parent Activity):

```
public void callFragmentMethod() {
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentByTag("SOME_TAG");
    if(fragment != null) {
        FreeFragment ff = (FreeFragment) fragment;
        ff.callSomeMethod();
    }
}
```

Pass the reference of the activity to the adapter and call above method from adapter. Or, to make the code more beautiful and easier to maintain and extend, define and interface with above method, have the activity extending the interface and send the interface as reference to adapter.

Comment: Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentByTag("SOME_TAG"); In this line which tag need to be written? From where I can get this TAG?? Its urgent for me to call Fragment from DataAdapter.. Please Help...

Comment: When you're adding a fragment, you're adding it by specifying an view group id where the fragment goes and an optional tag, that you define yourself. You can then get the the fragment either by tag, either by id.

Answer (score 0):

so if your adapter have access to FragmentActivity, you must call FragmentManager and further call fragment

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = yourFragmentActivity.getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
// Create new fragment and transaction
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, yourFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

easy step to handle this condition

1)create one Interface give any name

2) define method inside as per ewquirement example MyCommumicator
example i want to refreshData so i define method inside my interface like

```
public void refreshData();
```

now take reference of interface in adater like

```
MyCommumicator myCommumicator;
```

3)implement that interface into your Fragment and implement method.

4)create Constractor of Adapter like

```
 public TicketAdapter(other params...,MyCommumicator MyCommumicator){
   this.myCommumicator = myCommumicator;
}
```

6) Time of calling just call like this

```
myCommumicator.refreshData();
```

now enjoy

**ANOTHER WAY**
Use LocalBroadCast.